# Index Returns Data not normally distributed: Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a bunch of index prices and returns which appear to be normally distributed. But stats.normaltest() keeps giving zero p-values for this.
Here is the code for getting the returns:

```
returns = df.pct_change()
```

Now here's the matrix for the returns data:
[image]

As you can see, for some reason the distributions get skewed to the right. FYI I replaced the infinity values with NaNs, and used fillna(method='ffill') to fill in the NaNs with prices. Can someone please advise on a) Why am I getting p-values of zero? and b)Why are the returns getting skewed to the right? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. I am not sure why the returns getting skewed, but maybe you should avoid doing it in this format. Start simpler: Get the returns for each equity/TS you are working with, and plot it on an individual histogram.
2. This shouldn't be an issue, but in general, you should use log returns, so if `ts` is your time series as a `numpy` array, its

`returns = np.log(np.diff(ts))`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. I cleaned up the data and now they appear normally distributed. But p-values are still very close to zero. Not sure why. Will try your approach. Hope it works. Thank you...